# Android 6.0 Website doesn't render Mobile View LG G4

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, browser

I got a brand new LG G4 H815 Running Android 6.0. I've searched everywhere with no answer to the issue I'm facing.

For some reason, Mobile View in either Chrome, Firefox, Stock Browser, WebView doesn't render properly the website. i.e: This is what I see using Chrome:

[image: Arstechnica MobileView] [image: Stackoverflow]

Now, If I activate Request Desktop Site, it works like it should

[image: Arstechnica]

This is getting really annoying as I'm unable to use the phone as it should, every app that uses WebView doesn't render properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your apps are updated.

It looks like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` gets deleted and your browser renders page as if it's for PC (while stackoverflow determines when to serve PC/mobile version by User-Agent, not screen size). I'll suggest connecting via WiFi (or other carrier SIM card) or restoring the phone to factory settings.

You can check what is wrong with this short guide to Chrome debugging (based on the one I wrote for [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/152426/177898)):

- download Google USB Drivers & ADB on your PC
- plug your phone in
- run `adb devices`, it should say your device is unauthorized
- on your phone, you will get a window, select "Always trust this computer" and Yes
- open Chrome on both your PC and phone
- on PC, open Developer Tools on any page (f.e. about:blank)
- select (hamburger)->More tools->Inspect devices...
- make sure USB is checked
- your device should appear on the left
- open StackOverflow on your phone
- on PC click on your device and select Inspect on your working tab
- reload the tab

Then check for errors (maybe you get 500s because of Adblock-like app on your phone?) and if none, open `<head>` tag and check if you have following lines just below `<link rel="stylesheet" ...>` tags:

[image]

You can also provide report from http://amibeingtracked.com/ (even if said site doesn't wish to work for me).